# webpack hot reload always does full reload even with small change

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

Not sure if there is an error in my config but webpack hot reload ends up reloading the entire app when I make a change instead of just inserting the new change.

If I do something like change an inline style from `background: "red"` to `background: "green"` it will trigger a full reload rather than just hot updating.

Here is my app code:

**app.tsx**

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
}

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('app'));
root.render(
  <div>
    asdss
    <input
      style={{
        position: 'fixed',
        zIndex: 9999,
        background: 'red',
      }}
    />
  </div>
);
```

webpack.js

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
require('babel-polyfill');

const plugins = [
  new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
    template: 'index.html',
    publicPath: '/',
  }),
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ process: 'process/browser.js' }),
  new CopyWebpackPlugin({
    patterns: [{ from: 'src/assets/img/favicons', to: 'assets/img' }],
  }),
];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  plugins.push(
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'),
    })
  );
  plugins.push(
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: 'process/browser',
    })
  );
}

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: ['babel-polyfill', './src/index.tsx'],
  },
  devtool: 'inline-cheap-source-map',
  output: {
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].[fullhash].js',
    path: path.resolve('./dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
          transpileOnly: true,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
        use: [{ loader: 'babel-loader' }],
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        use: ['json-loader'],
        type: 'javascript/auto',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 8192,
              outputPath: 'assets/img/',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|otf)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'assets/fonts/',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  plugins,
  stats: 'none',
  mode: 'development',
  devServer: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    open: false,
    hot: true,
  },
};
```

Comment: In general, you want to break things up into separate components. If everything's defined in the root level, you'll get a lot of redraws when state changes. Put the `input` in its own functional component and then changes specifically for it won't trigger a whole app refresh.

Comment: I tried that and unfortunately it still does